# C3js Tooltip to appear on any hover within line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, c3.js

As you see in the example in the link below, the tooltip appears when you hover the mouse at any location in the line chart (even in white space)

https://bl.ocks.org/eesur/a9d87488a601bf6064e5

However, in the following example, the tooltip only appears when the mouse hovers close to the data point

https://c3js.org/samples/tooltip_format.html

I am having trouble getting the tooltip to behave like the one in the first link. Is this a CSS issue? The C3js.org reference doesn't seem to mention anything about it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Issue would be in you d3 code. Can you post your sample code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question correctly at first (deleted my answer). I'll get it right now. It's very weird though, because the first link's example should not be working since this versions of c3 and d3 are not even compatible. But it's not a css issue, my guess it's the way that the 'c3-event-rect's are being generated.You can observe as they meet the hover area of each point and they're not present in c3.js newest samples

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the sizing of the c3-event rects?